# Passing multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make  2x2 array, initialize it to 0, and pass it to functions.

I have tried initializing it with

```
int array[2][2] = {0}
```

but only the first 5 values come out as 0.

A bigger problem for me is passing the array to a function.

A 2 dimensional array is a pointer to pointers right? So I should be able to pass it as;

```
function(**array);
```

Is this correct?

When I try to access this array in the function can I access it in the format of

```
void function (int **array){
    array[0][2] = choice
}
```

as this does not work and I assume somewhere I have to define the size of the array.

Thanks.

Comment: "but only the first 5 values come out as 0." <- There are only four values in the array. You have 2×2 elements.

Comment: @DanielFischer The first row is [0][0],[0][1],[0][2] is it not?

Comment: No, the first row is `[0][0], [0][1]`. With an array `type array[dim];`, the valid indices are 0 through `dim-1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"A 2 dimensional array is a pointer to pointers right?" – wrong. A 2 dimensional array is just that – a 2 dimensional array; that is, an array of one-dimensional arrays.

If you want to pass a 2x2 array to a function, use a pointer to a 2x2 array:

```
static void function (int (*array)[2][2]){
    //(*array)[0][2] is out of bounds...
    (*array)[1][0] = 3;
}

int main(void) {
    int array[2][2] = {{0}};
    function(&array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an alternative to passing an `int(*)[2][2]`, it is often useful and convenient to pass an `int(*)[2]`, so that you can use `array[i][j]` in the function. The call would here be `function(array);`, and the prototype `static void function(int (*array)[2]);`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Good point. Similarly for one-dimensional arrays, it can be convenient to pass an `int*` rather than an `int(*)[2]`, to allow more convenient notation and variable array lengths.